# How does Rails set the root directory during initialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are two blog posts and a rails cast on how Rails creates an application, but neither explains how Rails finds and sets its own root-directory.

- http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2014/08/24/digging-rails-how-rails-initializes-itself/
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/299-rails-initialization-walkthrough?view=asciicast

What they do explain is how, through an `inherited` hook mainly, the class of the application is set and how it is then instantiated via delegation by the `#initialize`-method.

What they largely omit to my regret, however, is how Rails finds and sets its root directory, which I need in order to instantiate the application: `/Engine` and `/Configuration`-classes.

For example, in the first blog post, `Rails.application.root` is already there:

```
    Rails::Server.new.tap do |server|
    require APP_PATH
    Dir.chdir(Rails.application.root)
    server.start
```

Where and how does Rails set its root-directory?

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.application` delegates `root` to its configuration object, which is an instance of `Rails::Configuration`. That class is a subclass of `Rails::Engine::Configuration`. and the root directory is passed in as an initialization arguemtn .

You can see Rails.application.config being defined, with a method to determine the application root, in the [source code here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/21b32bb2a8001240e3e2c42811e2777d0411837d/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L376-L378):

```
def config #:nodoc:
  @config ||= Application::Configuration.new(self.class.find_root(self.class.called_from))
end
```

The `#find_root` method uses another method, [`#find_root_with_flag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L665-L675), to traverse the directory path upwards until it finds a folder containing `config.ru`.